# How to add AdMob interstitial ad

Tags: java, android, import

How to add AdMob interstitial ad?

I used to display AdMob banner on my future apps, and I'd like to give a try to the interstitial ads.

```
package com.codecanyon.xxxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.randombot.swaptheglyph.SwapTheGlyph;
import com.randombot.swaptheglyph.utils.Resolver;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements Resolver {

    private static final boolean ADS = true;

    private AdView adView;

    private String facebook;
    private String twitter;
    private String market;
    private String randombot;
    private String appName;
    private String googlePlay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.facebook = getString(R.string.facebook);
        this.twitter = getString(R.string.twitter);
        this.market = getString(R.string.market);
        this.randombot = getString(R.string.randombot);
        this.appName = getString(R.string.app_name);
        this.googlePlay = getString(R.string.google_play);

        // Create the libgdx View
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.hideStatusBar = true;
        cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
        cfg.useCompass = false;
        cfg.useImmersiveMode = true;
        cfg.useWakelock = false;

        if (ADS) {

            // Create the layout
            RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

            // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow()
                    .addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            View gameView = initializeForView(new SwapTheGlyph(this), cfg);

            this.adView = new AdView(this);
            this.adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_id));
            this.adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            this.adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

            /**
             * Invoking { requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); } will
             * make the add view not to be shown until the next event (updating
             * the ad every 60 seconds or pause/resume) By calling
             * setBackgroundColor we force the add to show itself as soon as
             * it's loaded.
             */
            this.adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            // Add the libgdx view
            layout.addView(gameView);

            // Add the AdMob view
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            layout.addView(this.adView, adParams);

            // Hook it all up
            setContentView(layout);
        } else {
            initialize(new SwapTheGlyph(this), cfg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (ADS) {
            adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ADS) {
            adView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (ADS) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(int which, int arg) {
        switch (which) {
        case RANKING: {

            break;
        }
        case SHARE: {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "Let's play " + this.appName + "!\n"
                    + this.googlePlay;
            sharingIntent
                    .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
            break;
        }
        case SHOW_URI: {
            String res = "";
            switch (arg) {
            case SHOW_URI_FACEBOOK:
                res = this.facebook;
                break;
            case SHOW_URI_TWITTER:
                res = this.twitter;
                break;
            case SHOW_URI_MARKET:
                res = this.market;
                break;
            case SHOW_URI_RANDOMBOT:
                res = this.randombot;
                break;
            }

            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(res);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myUri);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The imports are OK and the Google Play Services library is of course imported.

I use this example: AdMob Android Guides - Interstitial Ad.

Could someone tell me what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Call this function where to show Interstitial ad:

```
    public void AdMob() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("YOUR_TEST_DEVICE_ID").build();
        InterstitialAd interstitial; = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("YOUR_AD_ID");
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
              //Ads loaded
                  interstitial.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
              //Ads closed
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
             //Ads couldn't loaded
            }
        });
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```